# How do I show labels in a scene only once in a sprite kit game

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I am sure it must be very easy to implement but despite going at it in different ways I have been failed to implement it in my game. My game is made up of different scenes, Scene 1 is what I want my user to visit only twice, once when he opens the game very first time and tap play to move onto next scene (scene 2) which is basically a map and shows number of different activities to do. Scene 1 is visited only second time only when the user has completed all the activities showed by map on scene 2. Every activity when tapped on scene 2 leads to a different scene i.e. scene 3,4,5,6 but brings the user back to scene 2 when he completes a particular activity or fails to do so.

Now the problem I am facing is my scene 2 which shows a map also presents the user on his very first visit to the scene some welcome labels to describe about the game which need to be shown only once. When the user comes back to the scene 2 (map scene) after completing/failing an activity on a different scene he should not be presented with the labels again as they were meant to make him aware of the game for the first time only. I have tried using boolean variables to take care of this but I am failing because I believe the boolean variables used to track "if visitor already visited the scene" should not be saved in nodes userdata property as it seems everytime a user comes back to the scene 2. the boolean variable stored in userdata against particular label just resets to the default value and does not indicate that the user has been to the scene before.

This is pretty tricky but I am sure the solution would be simple for some reason not getting through my head.

Comment: Lets make sure I understood it correctly. You open the app on scene 1, you go to scene 2, display labels, start scene 3, fail, redirected to scene 2 where labels are displayed? And you want when he gets redirected to scene 2 for the labels not to be displayed?

Comment: Correct. One thing i would like to add even if the user succeeds in completing an activity on scene 3/4/5, he will still be directed back to scene 2 where he shouldn't be presented the labels again. One way to do so I can think of is to not create labels in viewDidLoad method of scene 2 rather in a different file or may be using NSUserDefaults to store the value of a boolean flag but that seems over complicated. There must be some way to do it using userdata property tied to labels.

Answer (score 0):

An ideal way is to separate your scenes from the data model.

The second way is to use a global setting to replace states stored in a scene node.

Every time the scene is reappearing, all nodes are reloading by default. So the info stored in the node is only related to scene but the game data model.

You are on the way to an exciting game programming design. Have fun.

Comment: The thing is the way Apple has demonstrated development of games using Sprite Kit framework, you are expected to deviate from their usual model-view-controller approach. But yet they have explained to separate data from logic by using plists and userdata property.I agree that when a scene is reloaded, all the nodes get reloaded and that's how my booleam variable stored in userdata resets naturally. But I believe there would be a way to stop the data stored in userdata property from being reset, as what is the benefit of having userdata property then.

Comment: User data is for scene related objects, like animation or node rendering. Game logic should be independent of scene even sprite kit if possible. Especially for a large game. You may choose different designs, just FYI.

Answer (score 0):

You can workaround the problem by giving your scene a name and check it on `viewDidLoad`.

After the user win/loses in scene 3, you create scene 2. Give that scene a name, for example `scene.name = "scene_failed"`, then present it to the user.

```
let transition = SKTransition.flipVertical(withDuration: 1.0)
let next_scene = Scene_Two()
next_scene?.name = "scene_failed"
self.view?.presentScene(next_scene!, transition: transition)
```

This way, when `viewDidLoad` function from scene 2 is called, it will trigger the if.

```
if scene?.name == "scene_failed"
{
     // redirected from scene 2
     hide_labels()
}
else
{
     // the scene has no name. so for sure it came from scene 1
     show_labels()
}
```

By giving you scene names, you can always know from what scene you transitioned.